# What is the difference between getLayoutPosition() and getAdapterPosition()?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between `getAdapterPosition()` and `getLayoutPosition`?

https://proandroiddev.com/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1. I have read this article, but don't really understand the part about `getLayoutPosition()`

Please explain it and the process behind it in simpler terms.

When would you use either while building an app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

`getAdapterPosition()` returns the updated position for the current `ViewHolder` object right after any of the `notify*()` calls.

`getLayoutPosition()` returns the updated value a bit later, after a new layout has been dispatched.

## Long Answer

### getAdapterPosition()

Adapter position returned by `getAdapterPosition()` will be updated immediately in one of the `notify*` calls that you make when your data source in `Adapter` changes:

```
notifyItemInserted(...)
notifyItemRemoved(...)
...
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

For example, if we look into `notifyItemInserted()` then it will invoke:

```
notifyItemInserted(int position)
              |
              v
             ...
              |
              v  
public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(null);
    if (mAdapterHelper.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)) {
        triggerUpdateProcessor();
    }
}
```

`mAdapterHelper.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)` will basically update `mPendingUpdates` that is used for retrieving a current adapter position. The next call `triggerUpdateProcessor()` will request a layout update, but more in the next section.

Now, if you call `getAdapterPosition()` for your `ViewHolder` right afterwards, it will return the updated position. However, `getLayoutPosition()` will still return the old value.

### getLayoutPosition()

`triggerUpdateProcessor` will call `requestLayout()` and return. That will schedule the layout update of `RecyclerView` (later `onLayout` will be invoked to signal the layout change):

```
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(null);
        if (mAdapterHelper.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)) {
            triggerUpdateProcessor();
        }
    }
```

That requires some time, though, but the update will become possible after `onLayout` callback is fired and `dispatchLayout()` is called:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    ...
    dispatchLayout();
    ...
}
```

Basically, after `onLayout` returns, the layout position will already be updated.

### Illustration

This can be illustrated with a simple `RecyclerView` in which `notifyInserted()` is called when a new element is added at the top of the list:

```
...
        public void addElementToHead() {
            elements.add(0, "New Element");
            notifyItemInserted(0);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Adapter position : " + currentFirstHolder.getAdapterPosition() +
                    ", Layout position : " + currentFirstHolder.getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
...
```

In this case, `currentFirstHolder` is a `ViewHolder` that corresponds to the initial first element in the adapter. However, after a new element is added as a first element, a position of `currentFirstHolder` must change to `1`. So, `getAdapterPosition()` is `1`, while `getLayoutPosition()` is still `0` because `RecyclerView` hasn't completed a layout update yet.

[image]

Here I log the content of the `ViewHolder` to show how it changes after `onLayout` is finally called:

```
...
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "From RecyclerView#onLayout - Adapter position : " +
            viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + ", Layout position : " + viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
...
```

So, it will look as below (it will be shown right after the first toast is gone):

[image]

Now, the full relevant code can be seen below. I didn't include layouts and other files for brevity.

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        MyRecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.add_element_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> adapter.addElementToHead());
    }

    private static class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        private RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                elements.add("Element " + i);
            }
        }

        public void addElementToHead() {
            elements.add(0, "New Element");
            notifyItemInserted(0);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Adapter position : " + currentFirstHolder.getAdapterPosition() +
                    ", Layout position : " + currentFirstHolder.getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        private RecyclerViewHolder currentFirstHolder;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView.setText(elements.get(position));

            if (position == 0) {
                currentFirstHolder = holder;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return elements.size();
        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private final TextView textView;

            public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.element_view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyRecyclerView.java

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "From RecyclerView#onLayout - Adapter position : " +
                viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + ", Layout position : " + viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which scenarios would you use either of them? Ex: Click events, notifications, pop ups, etc. and why? Thank you!

Comment: @CodingChap I would almost always use `getAdapterPosition()` in my `RecyclerView` because `getLayoutPosition()` is usually used by `RecyclerView` components internally. Maybe there's a use case for it but I can't manage to recall it right now.

Comment: @CodingChap `triggerUpdateProcessor()` calls `requestLayout()`. `requestLayout()` will signal the system that our layout has to be updated and returns. Then, after some time the system invokes an `onLayout` method through which the layout position is updated.

Answer (score 0):

the `getLayoutPosition()` function returns the position of the `ViewHolder` in terms of the latest layout pass but `getAdapterPosition()` returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder and that this might be different than the `getLayoutPosition()` if there are pending adapter updates but a new layout pass has not happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

**`getAdapterPosition()`** is deprecated and the new method is **`getBindingAdapterPosition()`**

Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder with respect to the `RecyclerView.Adapter` that bound it.

---

**`getLayoutPosition()`**

Returns the position of the `ViewHolder` in terms of the latest layout pass.

This position is mostly used by `RecyclerView` components to be consistent while `RecyclerView` lazily processes adapter updates.

---

[Official doc ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getLayoutPosition())

[Medium ref](https://proandroiddev.com/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1)